# Instagram Graph Api Does not work for other

Tags: instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I got the permissions for instagram_basic instagram_manage_insights vs pages_show_list.

When a user other than me wants to connect gives the error; (#100) Object does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permission or reviewable feature, or does not support this operation. This endpoint requires the 'pages_read_engagement' permission or the 'Page Public Content Access' feature or the 'Page Public Metadata Access' feature. They do not consider my application sufficient to get the Pages_read_engagement permission. When we tried to connect with another account again, we were able to connect this time. But it is not usually connected. Do I really need this permission or do you have any other recommendations?

Not: The accounts we tried are connected to a business account and a facebook page.

I want to get insights about accounts

Not:problem solved after getting permission

Comment: The problem solved after getting permission

Comment: please how did you get permission?